# Tableau Epoch to DateTime with TimeZone

Tags: tableau-api

Data has `hour` field (String datatype). The timestamp is in milliseconds. This is working -

```
DATEADD('second',INT(INT([Hour])/1000),DATETIME('1970-01-01'))
```

However, this is NOT WORKING -

```
DATEADD('hour',-7,(Date("1/1/1970") + (INT(INT([Hour])/(1000*86400))))
```

The above is returning NULL. `-7` is to adjust for my Timezone.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to get it done. May help someone.

Changed the second one to this -

```
DATEADD('hour',0,(DATETIME("1970-01-01") + INT((INT([Hour])/(86400*1000)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

As a reference, extract from Tableau own [knowledge base](https://kb.tableau.com/articles/issue/dates-display-unix-epoch-instead-of-date-datetime):

> To convert the field to UTC time, use the following calculation:
>
> DATEADD('second', [Unix time field], #1970-01-01#)
>
> To convert the field in Unix time to a different time zone, use the
> following calculation:
>
> DATEADD('minute', INT([Unix time field]/60 + ),
> #1970-01-01#)
>
> For example, to convert the field in Unix time to India Standard Time
> (IST), use the following calculation:
>
> DATEADD('minute', INT([Unix time field]/60 + 330), #1970-01-01#)